# How to Apply diagonal cut in imageview in xamarin cross platform?

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am new in Xamarin hybrid application. How to apply diagonal cut view in the image?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the diagonal view from the below code.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 



xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"


             x:Class="PEMS.Views.Profile"

            xmlns:xamvvm="clr-namespace:Xamvvm;assembly=Xamvvm.Forms"

            xmlns:xfShapeView="clr-namespace:XFShapeView;assembly=XFShapeView"

        xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"

         xmlns:fftransformations="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Transformations;assembly=FFImageLoading.Transformations"

        Title="CornersTransformation" BackgroundColor="White">

       <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <ffimageloading:CachedImage
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,.5"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            Source="profile_background.png" 
            />

        <xfShapeView:ShapeView
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,.5,400, 1600"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Rotation="-90"
            ShapeType="Triangle"
            WidthRequest="400"
            Color="White" />

        <Label
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".6,.6,.5,.1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            FontSize="34"
            HorizontalOptions="End"
            LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
            Text="Some content here."
            TextColor="White" />

    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by diagonal cut view in the image? Can you provide example or mockup?
[This](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) library is excellent for all the image transformations and caching, but since its unclear, I am not sure if it can help you.

Comment: I need below attached diagonal image view.

Comment: @ARS, you mean you want to crop imageview?

Comment: Yes. I did a diagonal cut of the image view. but how to make the automatic move and zoom effect in image view (like ken burns effect).

Comment: If you are looking for something like Parallax view, then you can try one of the following libraries/implementations:  https://github.com/DevsDNA/XFParallax; https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls/xamarin-parallax-view; https://www.thewissen.io/creating-a-parallax-carousel-in-xamarin-forms/